# Deserialization of object using Urban Dictionary API + NewtonSoft

Tags: c#, json.net

I have been trying to deserealize a JSON object and have a different class to hold the values. I want to be able to use it to define words with the urban dictionary api.

```
public void Define(string Word = "")
    {
        if (!Word.Equals(""))
        {
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            string value = client.DownloadString("http://api.urbandictionary.com/v0/define?term=" + Word);
            var ud = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List>(value);
            string defintion = ud.definition;
            Console.WriteLine(defintion);
        }      
    }
```

This is code in one of my classes and here I'm just using the API to get the JSON and then parsing it to my other class:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace botTesting
{
    [Serializable]
    class UrbanDictionary
    {
        [Serializable]
        public class List
        {
            [JsonProperty("defintion")]
            public string definition { get; set; }
            public string permalink { get; set; }
            public int thumbs_up { get; set; }
            public List<string> sound_urls { get; set; }
            public string author { get; set; }
            public string word { get; set; }
            public int defid { get; set; }
            public string current_vote { get; set; }
            public DateTime written_on { get; set; }
            public string example { get; set; }
            public int thumbs_down { get; set; }
        }
        [Serializable]
        public class RootObject
        {
            public List<List> list { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

I just want to retrieve the definition property, but every time I run the code, I get nothing and no errors are outputted either. How can I fix this so that I know what's going on? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would recommend [quicktype.io](https://quicktype.io/) as it will generate the C# classes for given JSON

Comment: @Minijack I used json2csharp.com, it converted the website.

Comment: in my opinion [this generated code](https://app.quicktype.io?share=RPvt5xYOayTgH84wOnw3) looks much better. and gives a method to serialize/deserialize

Comment: `var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(value);`

Comment: `result.Definition` should work.

Comment: @Minijack I've tried it and I get nothing, the console is blank but has a space in it.

Comment: @TheGeneral this worked but for some reason, everything other than definition works... (ie author, example, etc.)

Comment: maybe remove `[JsonProperty("defintion")]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(value);
```

also remove

```
[JsonProperty("defintion")]
```

There is no json property called `defintion` which is a spelling mistake

Comment: As OP, to add on, I got the definition by doing `result.list.ElementAt(//index).definition);`

Answer (score -1):

This sample deserializes JSON into a dictionary.

```html
string json = @"{
  'href': '/account/login.aspx',
  'target': '_blank'
}";

Dictionary<string, string> htmlAttributes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);

Console.WriteLine(htmlAttributes["href"]);
// /account/login.aspx

Console.WriteLine(htmlAttributes["target"]);
// _blank
```

Look at this link,[Deserialize a Dictionary](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeDictionary.htm)